# How do you absolute position UIElements onto Image background?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to make an interface where a background image represents points of interest and buttons are placed absolutely at those points. If the screen size changes so should the background image and buttons, but the absolute positions relative to the background image should remain the same.

Is there any nice way to do this in UWP without a lot of custom code? Ideally I'd like to design this interface in the XAML.

I thought I could use a canvas but I can't seem to resize the canvas and it's elements. A canvas isn't another window or computer monitor I can just resize.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Find the scale ratio with a simple math using App size and Orginal Img size. Then use that ratio to place that Button

Comment: Correction use `ActualSize` not App size

Comment: How do you set the Stretch property background image?